# Reading dataset and producing multiple scatter subplots

Tags: python, scatter-plot, subplot

I have the following data (dataset name is 'data' in the code below) and code. So far my code plots one scatterplot at a time; I need to change the company name manually if I am to get a specific scatterplot for a specific company. I  am looking to be able to go through the dataset below in one blush such that my prospective code reads the company name and executes the manipulations captured in the existing code below and ultimately produces separate scatterplots (ie subplots) for both companies Company1 and Company2 without one scatterplot overwriting or superimposing on the other. I was thinking I could use a for loop to go through the lines of code that I have below, but I am missing smth. Can someone please provide some insight?

Thanks in advance.

**Dataset:**

```
Date       Company  Cum_FootTraffic 
1/1/2015   Company1     450
1/3/2015   Company1     464
1/4/2015   Company1     481
1/5/2015   Company1     500
1/8/2015   Company1     508
………………………………………………………………
6/30/2015  Company1     810
4/2/2015   Company2     203
4/3/2015   Company2     208
4/4/2015   Company2     211
4/5/2015   Company2     218
4/8/2015   Company2     223
4/10/2015  Company2     234 
…………………………………………………………………
8/10/2015  Company2     498
```

**Code:**

```
data2=data.loc[data['username']=='Company1']

data2['Cum_FootTraffic_lag']=data2['Cum_FootTraffic'].shift(1)
data2['count']=data2['Cum_FootTraffic']-data2['Cum_FootTraffic_lag']
data2=data2.loc[data2['count']>=0]
data2=data2[['username','Date','Cum_FootTraffic','Cum_FootTraffic_lag','count']]

#Plotting data and manipulating plot size
#Scatterplot

dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(data2['Date'])
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(dates, data2['count'])
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```